# Error while returning an array from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have a question.

I am unable to compile my program.
This is a very simple program, that assigns an array, to a variable and passes it as an argument in a function. Now on returning this array it returns the array.

Now, I am facing a syntax error, that follows this way:

**p2.c:3:4: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
 int[] lifo(int[] arr)**

I am unable to resolve the error, for the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int[] lifo(int[] arr)
{
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[100],arr2[100],arr[100];
    int arr1_size,arr2_size,arr_size,i;
    printf("Enter size of array1: \n");
    scanf("%d",&arr1_size);
    printf("Enter size of array2: \n");
    scanf("%d",&arr2_size);
    printf("Enter elements of array1: \n");
    for(i=0;i<arr1_size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter elements of array2: \n");
    for(i=0;i<arr2_size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr2[i]);
    }
    printf("Combining 2 arrays: \n");
    arr_size=arr1_size+arr2_size;
    arr=lifo(arr1);
    for(i=0;i<arr1_size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you cannot return an array. You can return a pointer on an array, though: `int* lifo(int arr[])`. In your case, don't return anything as the function is probably working in-place

Comment: Can you explain me what does that error signify?

Comment: there no array parameter in C, there is no array return in C and the earth is not flat, `int *lifo(int *arr) { return arr; }`

Comment: also `int [] arr` is invalid C. Is this Java ?

Comment: We definitely can return an array in C using this very syntax. There is something wrong with the compiler.

Comment: @TrishantPahwa If you already know, why do you ask?

Comment: The LAST thing you should doubt is the compiler. Btw, you CAN'T really return an array. `return arr;` is equivalent to `return &arr[0];` due to array "decay"

Comment: just for completeness, you can't even **pass** an array ... the syntax looking like you could works because the types of function parameters are *adjusted*, array types become pointer types.

Comment: @TrishantPahwa As a rule, someone who blames the compiler is almost always wrong, particularly for beginners.

Answer (score 3):

In C, arrays can't be returned from a function, and **they can't be passed to a function** either. But let's start with this: Your declaration of an array is wrong here:

```
int[] lifo(int[] arr)
```

In C, the brackets in an array declaration go **after** the declarator. So, to write a function taking and returning an array, the "correct" syntax would look like this:

```
int lifo(int arr[])[]
```

If you try this, a good compiler will give you an error like this:

> error: ‘lifo’ declared as function returning an array

It just isn't allowed to return an array.

The compiler doesn't complain about the parameter `int arr[]` though: That's because of a special rule for function parameters -- if they have array type, they are automatically *adjusted* to the corresponding pointer type. So, the following function declarations are exactly the same:

```
void lifo(int arr[]);
void lifo(int *arr);
```

You can't pass or return arrays. But the syntax allows a function to *look like* it would take an array -- it instead takes a pointer to the first element of this array.

Comment: "The compiler doesn't complain about the parameter int[] arr though:", when does the committee will stop this non sense, where is my C17 ?

Comment: I'm not a fan of this type adjustment rule either, it IMHO obfuscates the code ... but there are worse historic things to finally ban (instead of just obsoleting them) -- and well, some even like type adjustment, with the argument that it's possible to express the intention that a function argument should point to an array...

Answer (score 1):

> `lifo(int[] arr)`

Turn this into:

```
lifo( int * arr )
```

or

```
lifo( int arr[] )
```

Note that even the second variant will still be passing a **pointer**, and **not** an array. (For one, you will not be able to determine the number of elements by `sizeof()`.) You are still able to use indexed access on `arr`, but you can do that on *any* pointer.

As for the return value, use `int *`. It is, after all, what you will be returning -- another **pointer**, not an array.

(Your function `lifo` is, of course, a non-op... I will assume this is for example's sake only.)

Comment: Also, **never** use `scanf()` for reading user input. **Especially** not without checking its return value. `scanf()` is for reading *formatted* input, known-good formatted stuff ideally written by your own program using `printf()` earlier. It really sucks at recovering from input errrors, providing meaningful error messages etc.; read whole lines using `fgets()` and then parse them. You have no idea whether you actually *have* read a value (and are invoking UB if you haven't).

Answer (score 1):

In C you always pass arrays by its address, for example its beginning. To do it you have to use pointers. It means that your function's definition is invalid. It should looks like:

```
int* lifo(int* arr)
{
   return arr; 
}
```

But this implementation does not have any sense because the output points to the same location as the input. Please refer to the books which explain you how the arrays are handled in C.

Comment: "But this implementation does not have any sense because the output points to the same location as the input.", this is a commun idom to return a parameter pointer. see every str* function for example.

Comment: @Stargateur: The str* functions *do* something with their parameters before returning one of them, though...

Comment: @DevSolar well, "(Your function lifo is, of course, a non-op... I will assume this is for example's sake only.)" ;)